# C++ using STL: Stack and Queue

Tags: c++, stl, stack, queue

My homework asks:

> > One day’s data set is available in file lot.txt on First Class.
>
> Arrival/Departure Code:       char (A or D) License                       string (ex. BOSS)
>   Time                          integer value representing military time
>
> A EARLYBIRD 630 A WORKER 700 A CEO 730 A CLERK 730  A MANAGER 800  A
>   VP 900  D CLERK 930  A SHOPPER 1000 D CEO 1000 D EARLYBIRD 1030 D
>   WORKER 1100 A JANITOR 1100 D MANAGER 1130
>
> A vehicle should be recorded as a struct containing the license and
>   the arrival time.  For simplicity, time will be an integer
>   representing military time.    Include the C++ string class.
>   struct Vehicle  {     string license;     // license value         int
>   arrival;      // arrival in military time ( 0 – 2359) };
>
> Read in the lines of the data files and recreate the movement of cars
>   in and out of the parking lot.   Vehicles are charged $8.00 per hour
>   for the duration of their stay.  Partial hours are rounded up.   You
>   can assume that only owners of cars in the lot arrive with a departure
>   request.   Report any cars left in the lot at day end as well as the
>   sum of charges.    Use the template stack and queue classes discussed
>   in lecture.
>
> For each arrival processed you should report: Car with license xxxxxx 
>   parked at xxxx  or Car with license xxxxxx was turned away at xxxx – 
>   LOT IS FULL!
>
> For each departure processed you should report: Car with license
>   xxxxxx  left at xxxx paying $xx.xx

I'm having trouble on the part when a car leaves. I'm not to familiar with stack and queue but as I understand it, stack is LIFO and queue is FIFO.

Here is what I have:

```
    struct Vehicle
    {
        char ad; // Arrival departure char
        string license; // license value
        int arrival; // arrival in military time
    };

    int main()
    {
        ifstream  fin;          // declare input file stream object 
        fin.open ("lot.txt");  //open data text
        stack<string> stack; // STL Stack object
        queue<string> q; // STL Queue object

        Vehicle v; // Object of struct Vehicle

        while(!fin.fail()){
            fin >> v.ad >> v.license >> v.arrival;
            if (v.ad == 'A' && stack.size() < 5){
                stack.push(v.license);
                cout << endl << "Car with license " << v.license << " parked at " << v.arrival;
            }else if(v.ad == 'A' && stack.size() >= 5){
                cout << endl << "Car with license " << v.license << " turned away at " << v.arrival << " - LOT FULL";
            }else if(v.ad == 'D'){
                string departingcar = v.license;

                for(int i=0; i<stack.size(); i++)
//am I on the right track with a for loop?
                    q.push(v.license);
                    stack.pop();
                    q.pop();
                    if(departingcar != v.license){
                        stack.push(v.license);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

I can read the vehicles in no problem but when I have to remove a vehicle from the stack, put them in a queue, and, then insert them back into the stack, I get lost.

Comment: Does your professor really use names like `lol.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your for-loop doesn't really make sense since right after you add something to the queue, you also pop whatever element was at the front, losing it forever since you never save it anywhere else.

I'm assuming what you're trying to-do here is find the car that was inserted in the stack, and remove it. If so, then do something like the following:

```
string departingcar = v.license;

//find and remove the license plate from the stack
for(int i=0; i<stack.size(); i++)
{
    if (departingcar != stack.top())
    {
        q.push(stack.top());
        stack.pop();
    }
    else
    {
        stack.pop();
        break;
    }  
 }

 //put the remaining cars back in the stack and empty out the queue
 while(!q.empty())
 {
    stack.push(q.front());
    q.pop();
 }
```

So basically what's happening here is we are adding cars to the queue that are not equal to the license-plate of the departing car.  If we encounter the license-plate from the car we want to remove, then we simply don't add it to the queue, but we remove it from the stack, and we exit the for-loop since we've found our car.  Next, we simply empty out the queue, pushing the cars we had previously removed from the stack back into the stack.